# Two internet Connections, one LAN - how to share?

Tags: lan, internet-connection, connection-sharing, proxy-server

Well, the title says what I'd like to achieve: I'd like some workstations connect through my 1st internet account and some through my second one.

1. The workstations are in a workgroup. They're not in a domain. So They don't have a server. One workstation has the internet connection and shares the internet through the whole LAN.
2. I have 2 ADSL internet accounts on that workstation.
3. The workstation's OS is Windows XP SP2.

I think I should define two http proxy servers on the workstation (probably via a software) and set the IE/Firefox proxy settings on each workstation to the appropriate proxy server. e.g. If I want station A to connect via ADSL1 I should set the proxy settings for ADSL1 as I have defined it in my workstation.
My question is:

1. is my approach correct? Do I need to use a third party software to be able to achieve what I have described or can I just use Windows connection sharing features?
2. What if I have to connect via ftp/telnet/etc? should I define other proxy servers and set the appropriate values in workstations as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's one approach...but it doesn't solve other protocols.

if you just want to load balance over the two networks it's as simple as making sure the route cost is the same...route /? for help i think.

The other possibility is to run a linux router in a VM and bridge network connections to the VM so you have a fully configurable router running on the XP host hardware.

Yet another approach is to make everything happen over socks proxies(this can handle any socks aware app or you can try a socks wrapper).  You could then run 2 different socks proxies that forward over different links.

Answer (score 4):

Connect each router to your switch and make sure they have different IPs in the same subnet. To define which internet connection is used by a particular machine, set its [default gateway](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ras_config_incoming_tcpip_defaultgw.mspx?mfr=true) value to the corresponding router.

Comment: Will workstations be able to see eachother in the network if I use your approach? Group1 workstations are connected to Hub1 and Group2 workstations are connected to Hub 2.

Comment: @Kamyar they should...broadcasts still work and direct connections still work...if i were going to take this approach i would look at multiple dhcp servers with different ip ranges in the same subnet and static mac to ip mappings

Answer (score 3):

Please also refer to @aking1012's answer.

If you are not familiar with routing setups, you can consider dual-WAN routers like the infamous [Cisco RV042 Dual WAN VPN Router](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9925/index.html). These offer reasonable performance at ~$150.

Similar products exist from other brands, and you can also consider dd-wrt on certain router hardware to get similar solution at a lower cost. ( refer to [Dual-WAN for simple round-robin load equalization](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Dual-WAN_for_simple_round-robin_load_equalization) for an example )