# Can I combine Wifi and Ethernet internet connections?

Tags: ethernet, connection, wifi-configuration

Can I make my computer use both Ethernet and Wifi connections to download files from multiparts supported servers simultaneously or download torrents faster and use both connections to download different parts of torrent file simultaneously, thus increasing my total speed for specific multipart supported download operations.

Note: I have 2 Internet services at my home both have their own routers so I want to use both of their speed at the same time to boost my total connection speed can I do that, if so how?

Comment: Also: http://superuser.com/questions/456328/how-to-bond-two-different-internet-connections, http://superuser.com/questions/660798/merging-two-incoming-broadband-lines-for-faster-internet, http://superuser.com/questions/224783/how-to-take-advantage-of-two-internet-connections-wifi-wired, [etc. etc.](https://www.google.ca/search?q=site%3Asuperuser.com+combine+internet+faster).

Comment: I agree with techie007 that the question has been asked before, but I must say all answers are **very** vague. No one has really done it, everyone is relating someone else's experience. There is no concrete sugestion available anywhere. So I cannot blame someone for trying once again to obtain a fully exhaustive answer: when can it be done, under which conditions, with which hardware and/or software.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae There *are* lots of accurate answers to the question being asked, and users posting the same vague question "how can I combine my internet connections for more speed" isn't going to gather more specific answers.

Comment: As has been said many times in many answers: true bonding requires participation from both ends (ie: you and your ISP). If OP wants to go a load-balancing route instead, then there's lots of info out there on how to set it up, depending on the user's specific existing infrastructure, specific needs, and such. Once they've made those basic decisions, and tried stuff, they will then probably have specific questions which will get specific answers

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Im actually asking something like "Download Booster" option on my phone, which uses wifi combined with cellular data to increase overall speed of my connection

Comment: @MariusMatutiae exactly there is no concrete answer or solution.
+those posts were asked 3-4 years ago so there could have been technological improvements as well.

Comment: Sounds good, but doesn't make it a different question. :)  Download Booster also only works for downloading files 30MB or larger (and only if the server supports multipart/range downloads), it's basically a download accelerator that will use the other connection for parts of the download.  Where as here you're just asking about combining Internet connections in general, with no specifics, no details, and no research effort that shows it's any different than the duplicates.

Comment: If you'd like newer answers to existing questions (because yours is no different, and you just want newer answers), perhaps earn a bit more rep and [place a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on one to draw attention. Also, keep in mind, it takes more than just my vote to close this. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Actually I did mentioned downloading torrent's for specifically multipart download, but yes maybe I should have made it more clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a technology called Bonded Broadband which combines two ADSL connections into a single connection. It would involve merging your connections into a single package, only [certain ISPs](http://www.eclipse.net.uk/products/connect/bonded-dsl/) provide this service.