# Sharing Data Link layer between two Virtual Network Adapter In Windows

Tags: windows, networking, lan, vlan, connection-sharing

I want to connect to two individual LAN Networks without adding a separate NIC, i tried to connect to both of them (the sub nets) with one single Network Adapter ( Local area network /* IPv4 -> advanced -> add ip*/).

But that does not fit the purpose of my application. I need a way to share the Data link layer only with two virtual LAN connection each one is connected to a different sub-network but physically with just one NIC ( one cable !! ).

Edit : i have Realtek 8111 gigabit ethernet NIC

Comment: What did work and what didn`t? What's the setup of those networks (e.g. are you able to reach them if you configure them separately)? This might help: [How to Quickly Add Multiple IP Addresses to Windows Servers](http://www.howtogeek.com/51741/how-to-quickly-add-multiple-ip-addresses-to-windows-servers/) Did you consider VLANs? Why did this not suffice?

Comment: i have to use gateway grouping, and to do that i need to have two network adapters to deal with in windows , with just one that's not possible

Comment: by gateway grouping i mean doubling my internet spped , there is a software called connectify that can do that ,  i have searched since this morning and i found a tool called realtek All Dignostics , i ru it and i was able to set up VLANs adapters , but non on them was able to reach the subnet that it was setup for :(

Comment: Does your switch/router support VLANs and have you configured it accordingly? My current understanding would bet hat you're trying to connect your machine to two separate networks which both have some form of internet access and you're trying to utilize both connections at once as a "shared" connection?

Comment: For now i just want to connect to my both network with just one NIC  with two seperate vuirtual adapter ( like two NIC but with just one )

Comment: Please supply some more information. What networks? What IPs/Subnetmaks do they have? Do you connect to them using a router or a switch? Where you able to ping other clients on those networks? Maybe try [this one](http://superuser.com/a/1000270/619267) as an easy solution. Clarify what you mean by "doubling your internet speed" as that might offer some different solutions. You won't easily be able to setup virtual network adapters from what I can tell.

Comment: I begin to understand VLAN a little bit, what i really need is a VLAN capable switch , because for now i'm using a non-VLAN switch and that's what is causing trouble.