# Windows 10 Bridged Network only uses 1 connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ethernet, bridge

I have an ethernet connection on my desktop PC and a WiFi connection on my phone. I'm using USB tethering to get my phone's wireless network to appear on my PC as an ethernet connection.

My PC ethernet connection appears as "Ethernet" and my phone connection appears as "Ethernet 2". I bridged Ethernet and Ethernet 2 and made a new connection called "Network Bridge" and it says there's internet access. However when I'm downloading anything or loading anything, the only connection it is utilising is the Ethernet connection.

I can confirm that both connections work on their own.

Have I done something wrong? What can I do to utilise both connections?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by having two internet connections? Faster download speeds? Ability to use your phone for the internet and still access network devices?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to achieve a higher download speed.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/224783/how-to-take-advantage-of-two-internet-connections-wifi-wired Although you might not end up with a faster download of one object. You can use multiple connection to do load-balancing (multiple downloads over multiple connections). But one download will always use one physical connection. (also see https://askleo.com/can_i_combine_two_internet_connections_to_get_a_faster_connection/)

Comment: Ah thanks. I actually intended to get a faster download of one file but I guess I'll just have to deal with it. Thanks again.